# Python Pandas Conditional Update

Tags: python, pandas

The problem is as follows:

- The columns are: first name, last name, department (consulting or sales, abbreviated into C and S respectively), employee id, and salary. The salary column doesn't have any function in this example; it's just to emphasize that there are actually lots of other columns.
- Certain names are duplicate *between* departments.
- Not sure if this helps, but the `first_name + last_name + id` forms a unique identifier for each row. I have to use this, because it's the shortest unique identifier which identifies the most duplicates in previous duplicate-removal scenarios (see rows 1 and 2). I can go one step further and concatenate this identifier with even more columns, but that's just not a very elegant solution.

The initial dataframe is as follows:

```
first_name | last_name | id | dept | salary
-------------------------------------------
sarah      | jones     | C1 | C    | 60000
sarah      | jones     | C2 | C    | 55000
robert     | jones     | C3 | C    | 50000
alice      | clarke    | C4 | C    | 40000
alice      | clarke    | S1 | S    | 40000
thomas     | roberts   | S2 | S    | 45000
```

I'd like to remove row 4 (the `alice clarke` row that's associated with the *consulting* dept) and keep row 5, but retain the consulting dept ID. That is, I should have:

```
first_name | last_name | id | dept | salary
-------------------------------------------
sarah      | jones     | C1 | C    | 60000
sarah      | jones     | C2 | C    | 55000
robert     | jones     | C3 | C    | 50000
alice      | clarke    | C4 | S    | 40000
thomas     | roberts   | S2 | S    | 45000
```

(IRL: I have two data sources, D1 and D2. D2 data is of a higher quality, but the ID used by D1 is more widely recognized, like an ISO standard in my field. So whenever D1 and D2 happen to give me the same row, I want to use the D1 ID, and the actual data from D2. )

The actual problem is a little more complicated than this MVWE (several duplicate-removal scenarios). I've tried cutting up the problem with some of my previous questions on duplicate removal or conditionally overriding values, but haven't been able to successfully tackle the whole thing, mostly because I've been unable to modularize the problem properly.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508586/python-pandas-updating-row-based-on-another-row-value) question on conditionally updating rows might help.

Comment: To clarify: do you _always_ want to keep the S duplicate, but with the C id?

Comment: One more confusion point: suppose you also have alice clarke C5. Now, is alice clarke S1 a duplicate of C4 or C5?

Comment: An example, while so useful it's basically a necessity, is not a substitute for actually saying what criterion you want to be applied.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave two different salaries for alice so we can understand which salary remains once filtered.

Comment: Clarification: if the row has records from both departments, then retain the record from department S, but use the ID from department C. If the person (row) only has records from *one* department (either one), do nothing. For e.g., Thomas Roberts (last row) is unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per some of the commenters your example is a little short on detail, but if I understand correctly, you basically have two data frames and want to keep some info from one, and other info from another.  Assuming you're actually starting with two dataframes and are in control of merging them, `combine_first()` should do the trick:

```
csv = io.StringIO(u'''
first   last     id  dept  salary
sarah   jones    C1  C     60
sarah   jones    C2  C     55
robert  jones    C3  C     50
alice   clarke   C4  C     40
thomas  roberts  S2  S     45
''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv, delim_whitespace = True)

csv2 = io.StringIO(u'''
first   last     id  dept  salary
alice   clarke   S1  S     43
''')

df2 = pd.read_csv(csv2, delim_whitespace = True)
df2.drop('id', axis = 1)

print df2.set_index(['first','last']).combine_first(df.set_index(['first','last'])).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   first   last    dept  id   salary
0  alice   clarke  S     C4   43.0 
1  robert  jones   C     C3   50.0
2  sarah   jones   C     C1   60.0
3  sarah   jones   C     C2   55.0
4  thomas  roberts S     S2   45.0
```

And of course you can sort as you see fit at that point.

Answer (score 0):

If the starting point is the initial data frame you provided, and given that there are only two `dept` types, you can `groupby` name and then `apply` a selection/swapping function:

```
# using initial data frame provided, copied to clipboard
df = pd.read_clipboard().drop(0, 0).drop(['|','|.1','|.2','|.3'], 1)

def choose_data(data, chosen_field, chosen_value, swap_field):
    if len(data[chosen_field].unique()) > 1: 
        chosen = data[data[chosen_field]==chosen_value]
        chosen[swap_field] = data.ix[data[chosen_field]!=chosen_value, swap_field].values
        return chosen
    return data

(df.groupby(['first_name','last_name'], as_index=False)
   .apply(choose_data, 
          chosen_field='dept', 
          chosen_value='S', 
          swap_field='id')
   .reset_index(drop=True)
   .sort_values('id')
)
```

Yields:

```
  first_name last_name  id dept   salary
0      sarah     jones  C1    C  60000.0
1      sarah     jones  C2    C  55000.0
2     robert     jones  C3    C  50000.0
3      alice    clarke  C4    S  40000.0
4     thomas   roberts  S2    S  45000.0
```

Note that the `reset_index()` and `sort_values()` are basically cosmetic, all that's really necessary is `groupby()` and `apply()`.